# Using Pickers in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I have a basic screen in my iPhone MonoTouch (C#) application. This screen asks the user to choose their Gender and BirthDate. However, I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Ideally, I think I would want a textbox. When the textbox gets focus, a picker at the bottom would appear in something like a dialog. I'm not even sure if this is the recommended user approach on iOS.

oddly, every sample I find online is just an example of someone showing a picker on a screen. However, I have a need for multiple pickers and I'm not sure what the best user experience is. any ideas?

Comment: well from what you posted what fields would you need to use multiple selection.. can only have one Gender, One BirthDate so based on your question it doesn't make sense what your expectations are.. do some more research or post a question that's relevant to what it is that you are truly looking for...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at MonoTouch Dialog, it makes things like this pretty easy to do: https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog